# Acrobat javascript mobile devide change page after time

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, acrobat

I need to insert a specific *acrobat javascript* into a PDF that changes page after a minute and come back to the first page.
I used the code

```
app.setTimeOut("pageNum = 0;",60000)
```

This code working properly on Windows but if I move the file to Android device doesn't work.
Someone could help me to understand how to solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't solve it, at least not with that code. Most PDF viewers on mobile devices don't process JavaScript in PDF files and the ones that do, do not support the entire Acrobat Desktop JavaScript API. I know for a fact that Adobe Acrobat Reader Mobile and Readdle PDF Expert don't support the app.setTimeOut method. Foxit MobilePDF 9 might but I haven't tested it and those are the only three that I know of that support any JavaScript at all.

Comment: I have tried it and doesn't work on mobile device. thanks anyway.